# How to sync file system synonym.txt file changes with SOLR UI?

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

I am trying to reload my core after updating the synonyms.txt file. Ideally, When I save changes in my synonyms.txt file then it should reflect the same changes when I open that file in SOLR UI. Post that I perform a core reload. In my case I am not able to see the file system changes on SOLR UI.

Solr version - 5.3

Comment: Reloading your core should definitely do it; are you doing a reload through the Solr UI?

Comment: Reloading the core is second part, the first thing is that I am not even able to see the file system changes through SOLR UI.

Answer (score 0):

you mention solrcloud tag, so if you are using solrcloud, you know about uploading conf files to zookeeper etc right?

look for 'upconfig' in [this doc](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/command-line-utilities.html)